# vertical scrollbar appears when nothing is there

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

I've put in a form on this page, on my computer it doesn't extend beyond the page bottom, yet a vertical scrollbar appears.

Here's the page:
http://kimkellermedia.com/test3/contact.html

I've inspected the page, and the weird thing is that it shows nothing there, saying the html stopped before the cut off point, so I'm not sure what to change to get rid of empty space.

Since it doesn't seem to be showing up for everyone, here's a big screenshot of what I'm seeing:  http://kimkellermedia.com/test3/example.html

Comment: I dont see a scroll bar there, in Ff. what browser are you testing this in

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Ff, it's appearing on my computer and at work, though I did have one friend who said they don't see the scrollbar either

Comment: I don't see the scrollbar either :)

Comment: If anyone doesn't see the scroll bar then I think he/she is using bigger screen or there is resolution setting difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content has a span having visibility:hidden, make it display:none. So that the space for the span will not be used.

I have tried by reducing the height of comment textarea and the scroll bar is gone now.
Please set the height of the scroll bar to 175px. It was because of the contents.

Now the scroll bar will not appear.

Comment: I'm just confused because I'm using the same background image, the same size, on another page: http://kimkellermedia.com/test3/about.html and there is no scrollbar

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I got it after checking both the pages. If you still get the scroll bar let me know.

Comment: This sounds like it would work, but I can't find any mention of a span or visibility:hidden.  I've looked through all my code, am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: <span id="fonttest" style="font: 99px testfont,_,serif; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">........</span>
This is the tag for the span. Either it is in the page directly or in master page. If you are still not able to find the span let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like I'm crazy, because I really can't find it.  I went through every page of code I'm using, ctrl f, and the span didn't show up.

Comment: Ok, no need to feel sorry. Let me give you more information. Do you use firebug?

Comment: That span is created in Modernizr.js. If you have created this js file then search "fonttest" in this file. You will get it.

Comment: Ok then use fire bug, we will find the span easily. Check the comment above.

Comment: oh wow, found it!  I changed it to display:none and it worked like a charm, thanks a million!